# Use select into insert SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I am trying to avoid one select before insert without success.

```
INSERT INTO `tableInfo`(`name`, `start_date`, `end_date` , `BelongTo`) 
VALUES ( (SELECT name FROM `tableInfo` WHERE id=38) as tmp , NOW(), NOW() , 38)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a subselect for a single value is a poor practice even if its not syntactically invalid sql, which I suspect this is.

Simply remove your `VALUES` and use an insert select statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tableInfo`(`name`, `start_date`, `end_date` , `BelongTo`) 
SELECT name, NOW(), NOW() , 38 FROM `tableInfo` WHERE id=38
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  INSERT INTO `tableInfo`(`name`, `start_date`, `end_date` , `BelongTo`) 
  SELECT name,NOW(), NOW() , 38 from tableInfo where id=38
```